# How to transport single servings of powdered drink mixes

Tags: food, drinks, moving

There are lots of drink mixes that come in powdered form: protein powders, meal replacement shake mixes, etc.

Usually these come in a big container of powder with a little scoop, and you scoop out the right amount and mix it with water.

How can I carry some single serving sizes of powder with me to mix with water while I'm on the go? I thought about using ziploc bags but it's hard to pour from the bag into the water cup without spilling powder everywhere.

Comment: Easier if you use a bag that doesn't have the zip: http://www.webstaurantstore.com/images/products/main/14772/124448/plastic-food-bag-6-x-8-sandwich-size-on-a-roll-1750-roll.jpg

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is exactly what a baby formula dispenser is for. They normally have three separated compartments with a top that you can rotate to easily empty the contents of a single compartment.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

If it's big enough for your servings, use Kinder Surprise eggs.

[image: Kinder Surprise Egg]

These are things you usually throw away but can use for storing various things.

Further, I think click-clack mint boxes could work as well.
[image]

Basically any small container you already have laying around, which is more or less air tight, could work. I have no experience with powders but if you have some free time, just try out all the things laying next to you!

Comment: Notice that, according to some websites around (never went deep on this one), Kinder Surprise is illegal in the U.S.A. I'm not saying it really is, I'm saying I read it around. But Kinder eggs are useful for other stuff like storing small jewelry or some coins.

Comment: Kinder eggs, to my complete astonishment, are indeed illegal in the USA. Extraordinary! But anything lying around will do - empty vitamin pill containers work too.

Comment: @Bamboo. OMG! Illegal?!? So in the USA it is legal to keep assault rifles at home but not Kinder eggs? In Italy it's just the other way around. How fun is the world we live in! :-)

Comment: @Lorenzo Yep! Non-edible items inside consumables is illegal in America!

Comment: @LorenzoDonati yep, weird as hell, don't make any sense - don't try buying cheese in USA either, there's some ruling about bacteria content that means it all tastes like plastic (sorry guys, but really, your cheese...!) But the UK has some pretty odd rules too, just not those ones...

Comment: Bamboo, evidence of the cheese thing? I've had cheese in England, Germany, Switzerland, Belgium, and here in the US, and I've had cheese here that is every bit as good as the best I've had abroad. We also get imported food. I hope you're not referring to the crappy kraft singles as if that represents cheese here.

Comment: There are some "extreme cheese" varieties that are banned by the FDA - first two on this link are understandably banned (!) But the raw milk ones are goood! http://www.cheeserank.com/culture/cheese-culture/cheeses-banned-in-the-us/#!/image-7

Answer (score 9):

Indian takeaway restaurants provide chutneys in small sealable plastic containers, about 3cm in diameter.  I collect these after a curry and they make perfect containers for individual doses of soluble drinks.

[image]

Comment: This also allows you to bring it already dissolved. But that may cut the effect on protein shakes. Also, you can drink it right out of the container, if you don't have anything around.

Comment: There's a smaller version for storing dipping sauce as well

Comment: These are also available at Baja Fresh for salsas and probably other mexicanish restaurants

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind not re-using the ziploc bag, and have something to cut with, then cut off one of the bottom two corners (just like how you'd turn a ziploc into a pastry bag). Now it's a funnel for easy pouring.

Another option: if you fold back the top of the ziploc bag (so the top inch or so is inside out, the zip seal part facing out) it'll pour better. Also reusable this way.

Other than that, there are small, plastic airtight containers intended for stuff like this.

Comment: I added a variation to this in my answer. Also, I was and reuse ziplock bags all the time. Lighter footprint.

Answer (score 2):

Put each portion of powder into a separate piece of paper and the fold it up. IE: Goodies or BC headache powder. You could put multiple portions in the same ziploc.

Comment: This also acts as a funnel when unfolded.

Answer (score 1):

Jars -- I use a small 16 oz peanut glass butter jar, but any will do -- if you aren't handling as much powder a [4 oz jam jar](http://www.jarstore.com/4-oz-Squat-Jelly-Jar-With-Your-Choice-of-Lid_p_50.html) should do perfectly for a single serving of around 30g of powder.

[image: 4 oz jar]

1. If around 16 oz, you can hold more servings as well as a household spoon (so you can portion out your powder)
2. Clear (so you'll know the contents)
3. Can be travelled with (I frequently fly with protein powder this way)
4. Can be very tightly sealed.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it's a good solution for carrying single-servings of drink mix, unless the single serving is close to the size of a peanut butter jar. This seems more like a solution for carrying multiple servings without carrying along the (sometimes large) original container.

Comment: Glass jars vary in size. I personally use a bigger one, because my protein powder usage is 60g/16 oz water. Obviously, one may go for a far smaller jar, maintaining all of the original benefits minus #1. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Snack size ziplock bags, and a small box. Measure a single serving into each ziplock bag. Place several bags in larger container such as ring box, eyeglass case, altoids tin, or whatever. The bag is air and water tight. The box protects the bag from rips, tears, punctures and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

When I did long cycling rides, I'd use the inexpensive, lightweight plastic bags.  When I needed a "serving", I'd bite off the corner and empty the contents into my water bottle.  The drink mix I was using had sugar and being able to empty the mix into the bottle without getting any on my hands or clothes was very convenient.  Nothing eco-friendly about the solution, but it met the needs I had for multi-day, long-distance rides.

Answer (score 0):

Reuse the tube that hydration tablets come in. E.g., Nuun or Hydralyte

Answer (score 0):

This thread got me thinking... Finally.

I need a single teaspoon dose for my drink. It occurred to me to try a drinking straw, paper or plastic. Fold an end over, heat seal or staple. Fill and seal.

I'm gonna try it.

Comment: Hi John, Welcome to Lifehacks.

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestions all. As a backpacker, I carry Gatorade mix for use with water that I filter. I also make up individual packets of instant coffee and sugar for the mornings.

Because of weight, what I do is take a plastic sandwich bag (the cheaper, the better), and place a single serving of whatever into the corner. I heat up the blade of a very sharp knife and cut the edges of the plastic bag to size, then pinch the edges together creating a seal. This creates a seal from the melted plastic. Be sure leave extra space in the bag so you can cut it without burning yourself and the package isn’t under much pressure.

You can also “double-seal” it using a lighter or a blow dryer/heat gun along the sealed edge. Heat slightly (until melty), then pinch together. Don’t burn yourself. Be sure to “test” the new seal to May sure it doesn’t leak.

Because the new “bag” is so small, it’s easy to tear a small side open and pour into a water bottle or cup. Very easy to do. The individual servings hold up well when I store them all together in a good quality Ziplock bag. Works well. If you have a vacuum [food sealer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vacuum%20sealers%20for%20food&t=iphone&ia=images&iax=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ebayimg.com%2Fimages%2Fi%2F372686387303-0-1%2Fs-l1000.jpg) that works great but the bags are a bit heavy and expensive. I use mine for dehydrated vegan meals I make for the trail.

Here’s a pack with Gatorade to take with me when I’m out. Because weight isn’t an issue unless I’m backpacking, I leave the ziplock part of the bag for slightly better storage. This is about a quarter of a “snack-size” bag. (2 Euro coin for scale)

[image: single serving]

Answer (score 0):

Plastic test tubes , or "doob tubes" that are normally used for joints. Im currently looking for the same thing, and thats as good of an idea as i can think of.